# Read reg_binary as string using Tregistry Class in delphi

Tags: delphi, registry

I am trying to get the reg_binary as string from a registry key.

This is my function

```
function ReadBinString(key: string; AttrName: string): string;
var
 ReadStr: TRegistry;

begin
// Result := '';
ReadStr := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
ReadStr.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

   if ReadStr.OpenKey(key, true) then
begin

  Result := ReadStr.GetDataAsString(AttrName);
end;

ReadStr.CloseKey;
ReadStr.Free;
end;
```

and here is my registry key Export :

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ZES\ACINFO]
"iamthere"=dword:00000001
"ArrayOrder"=hex:4d,79,45,78,63,6c,75,64,65
```

the problem is , the function returns empty string

I even tried running as administrator to make sure that it is not permissions.

Any help ?

Comment: Don't use `KEY_WRITE`. Remove that. Use `OpenKeyReadOnly`. Stop using `GetDataAsString`. Use `GetData` instead and then `TEncoding` to decode the ANSI byte array

Comment: For the record, you should also get in the habit of debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on my comment to the question, I'd use code like so:

```
function ReadBinString(RootKey: HKEY; Access: LongWord; const KeyName,
  ValueName: string; Encoding: TEncoding): string;
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(Access);
  try
    Registry.RootKey := RootKey;
    if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(KeyName) then begin
      SetLength(Bytes, Registry.GetDataSize(ValueName));
      Registry.ReadBinaryData(ValueName, Pointer(Bytes)^, Length(Bytes));
      Result := Encoding.GetString(Bytes);
    end else begin
      Result := '';
    end;
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For your data you would call it like so:

```
Value := ReadBinString(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 'Software\ZES\ACINFO', 
  'ArrayOrder', TEncoding.ANSI);
```

Notes:

- I have avoided hard-coding the root key.
- I have used `TEncoding` to decode the byte array to text. This is far more effective than `GetDataAsString`.
- I have allowed the caller to specify the encoding to be used.
- I have allowed the caller to specify the access flags.
- I have used `OpenKeyReadOnly` because we do not require write access.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Heffernan I came with this solution:

```
function ReadBinString(key: string; AttrName: string): string;
var
ReadStr: TRegistry;
hexStr : string;
I : Integer;
begin
// Result := '';
 ReadStr := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
 ReadStr.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

 if ReadStr.OpenKey(key, true) then
 begin

hexStr := ReadStr.GetDataAsString(AttrName);

hexStr := hexStr.Replace(',','');
for I := 1 to length (hexStr) div 2 do
Result:= Result+Char(StrToInt('$'+Copy(hexStr,(I-1)*2+1,2)));

end;

ReadStr.CloseKey;
ReadStr.Free;
end;
```

Thanks to David Heffernan again ... this worked for me :

```
    function ReadBinString(key: string; AttrName: string): string;
    var
      ReadStr: TRegistry;
      hexStr: string;
      I: Integer;
      Bytes: TBytes;
      Encoding: TEncoding;
    begin

      Encoding :=  TEncoding.ANSI;

      Result := '';
      ReadStr := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
      ReadStr.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      try

        if ReadStr.OpenKeyReadOnly(key ) then
        begin

          SetLength(Bytes, ReadStr.GetDataSize(AttrName));
          ReadStr.ReadBinaryData(AttrName, Pointer(Bytes)^, Length(Bytes));
          Result := Encoding.GetString(Bytes);

          // hexStr := ReadStr.GetDataAsString(AttrName);
          //
          // hexStr := hexStr.Replace(',','');
          // for I := 1 to length (hexStr) div 2 do
          // Result:= Result+Char(StrToInt('$'+Copy(hexStr,(I-1)*2+1,2)));

        end;

      except

      end;
      ReadStr.CloseKey;
      ReadStr.Free;
    end;
```

Comment: `GetDataAsString()` is designed to return the raw bytes as a hex-encoded comma-delimited string.  You are decoding that back to the raw bytes and then converting those values as-is into string characters.  To simplify that, you really should be using `ReadBinaryData()` instead to read the raw bytes directly, and then you can convert those to a String using `TEncoding.GetString()`. Like DavidHeffernan showed you.

Comment: Now, `KEY_READ` is needless, there is potential for leaking, i.e. `Free` might not be called, the `CloseKey` call is needless. I'm not sure what this adds beyond my answer.